# Disable Pylance for a specific command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I use [Python interactive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py) in Visual Studio Code.

I sometimes use the `display` command, which runs fine in the Notebook that is opened on the side, but Pylance marks it as: `"display" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)`. This probably happens because I am in a `.py` file, which doesn't recognize this command, but when running VSCode, it works just fine.

I would like to ignore this warning (only), how can I do that?

Illustration:

```py
x = 42
display(x) # Pylance flags this
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pylance can not suppress this warning only, it only can suppress one type of warning, such as this:

```
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to disabling the warning would be to explicitly import `display`:

```py
from IPython.display import display
```

That would avoid disabling a whole class of warnings - `reportUndefinedVariable` - that you might not want to disable.